# Android: set android:process for a receiver

Tags: android, process, broadcastreceiver, pid

My app has two processes A and B. I have a receiver which belongs to process B and I specify it through android:process in the manifest like below:

```
        <receiver
            android:name=".myapp.receiver.receiverB" 
            android:process=":processB" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="something" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

But I register receiverB in processA so that when I receive the intent from process A I can actually do something in the processB. But when I am debugging in receiverB, I find out that android.os.Process.myPid() always returns processA's ID.

I'm wondering how I'm able to get processB's id within the receiver? I thought setting android:process=":processB" can guarantee that the code running within receiverB must reside in processB.

Comment: "My app has two processes A and B" -- why do you think that this is a good idea?

Comment: there is some rationale behind but it would be somewhat complicated to explain the idea here...process A is the major one and it has to be light weighted